# How to use bitwise in Yii2

Tags: yii2, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

How can I use bitwise operators in Yii2?

```
| bitwise OR
& bitwise AND
~ bitwise NOT
! boolean NOT
```

If we have a query like this:

```
SELECT a_int_value | b_int_value  
FROM bitwise;
```

or how to use bitwise in 'andFilterWhere'

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['|', 'a_int_value', $this->b_int_value]);
```

don't work.

Comment: andFilterWhere seems to work just fine, could you add some examples of data you're using and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: also, reading the question again, are you sure you dont need a `$query->addSelect('a_int_value | b_int_value')`, it's a bit ambiguous whether you need to select a bitwise expression or use bitwise expression as query condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use also filterCompare

```
$query->andFilterCompare('a_int_value', $this->b_int_value, '|');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#filter-conditions

Comment: I tried your solution but when filtering nothing happens.